# Qt: Using QTransform object for rotate differs from setting setRotation() in QGraphicsItem

Tags: qt, pyqt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

While setting a `QGraphicsItem` rotation, I get different results upon the transformation origin point while using [`setRotation()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qgraphicsitem.html#setRotation) and using:

```
transform = QTransform()
transform.rotate(myAngle)
myItem.setTransform(transform)
```

In both portion of code, I set `setTransformOriginPoint()` to the same point.

Results are:

- While using `setRotation()` method, the item is rotated upon its transformation origin  point.
- While using the `QTransform` object, the item is rotated upon item's origin, that is, point *(0,0)*.

My code is more complex than that, but I think It applies the same. The `QGraphicsItem` is in fact a `QGraphicsItemGroup` and I can check the issue adding just one item, and in my rotation procedure change the `setRotation()` method for the `QTransform` object. The latter, ignores the `setTransformOriginPoint()`.

I'm having this issue for a while, and I dig a lot of resources. I browse the Qt C++ code, and I can see that the `setRotation()` method modifies a field calles `rotation` (a *real* value) in the `TransformData` structure within the `QGraphicsItem`. The origin point is also a two field *real* value in such a structure called `xOrigin` and `yOrigin` respectively. The transformation is stored in the `tranform` field. All this information is used in a variable called: `transformData`.

So, I don't get why the transformation set in the `transformData->transform` field is ignoring the values `transformData->xOrigin` and `transformData->yOrigin` at the time of being applied.

The code I used to test that issue is the following relevant part (I have an *rotate item* that receives mouse inputs and applies rotation to the item itself):

```
# This method using QTransform object....
def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    if self.pressed:
        parent    = self.parentItem()
        parentPos = parent.boundingRect().center()
        newPoint  = event.scenePos()
        iNumber   = (newPoint.x()-parentPos.x())-((newPoint.y()-parentPos.y()))*1j
        angle     = cmath.phase(iNumber)+1.5*math.pi
        self.appliedRotation  = (360-math.degrees(angle))%360 - self.angleOffset
        transform = QTransform()
        transform.rotate(self.appliedRotation)
        self.parentItem().setTransform(transform)

# ...Against this one using setRotation()
def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    if self.pressed:
        parent    = self.parentItem()
        parentPos = parent.boundingRect().center()
        newPoint  = event.scenePos()
        iNumber   = (newPoint.x()-parentPos.x())-((newPoint.y()-parentPos.y()))*1j
        angle     = cmath.phase(iNumber)+1.5*math.pi
        self.appliedRotation  = (360-math.degrees(angle))%360 - self.angleOffset
        self.parentItem().setRotation(self.appliedRotation)
```

On both, previously the `setTransformOriginPoint()` is set, but it's not a relevant part to show the code, but just to know that it is done.

I'm getting frustrated to not find a solution to it. As it seems so straightforward, why setting a rotation transformation matrix does not use the transformation origin point that I have set and while using `setRotation()` method works fine? That question took me to the source code, but now is more confusing as rotation is keeping separated from the transformation applied...

Answer (score 3):

I was solving the same problem. I found out that QGraphicsItem::setTransformOriginPoint() is accepted only for QGraphicsItem::setRotation(). It is ignored for QGraphicsItem::setTransform().

I use this code to reach the same behavior for QTransform():

```
transform = QtGui.QTransform()
centerX = item.boundingRect().width()/2
centerY = item.boundingRect().height()/2
transform.translate( centerX , centerY  )
transform.rotate( -rotation )
transform.translate( -centerX , -centerY )
item.setTransform( transform )
```

Comment: I will reach my code later and with time I'll check this for giving you a reply on this. I switched job and my project has been stopped for a while. Regards.